# Java Scanline Polygon Fill Algorithm

Tags: java, applet

I have just started learning computer Graphics and also new to JAVA. This my java applet which performs scan line algorithm it works well for certain cases. Can anyone help me out to know where am I actually wrong ?

You can view entire code here = http://codeshare.io/9uVUf
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `it works well for certain cases` tell us when/where it not works as you expected.

Comment: 1) Why code an applet?  If it is due to spec. by teacher, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should stop teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/). 2) For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example). 3) Try describing a) What you expected to happen b) What actually happened, and for utility c) Why you expected (a) to happen.

Comment: I found out that it works if co-ordinates are given in clockwise manner only. So do I need to sort the edges in clockwise manner ?? If yes how ??

Answer (score 0):

I've made something similar in C++ and OpenGL. Work with concave and convex, not sure if with all polygons.

I don't know if it's the best solution, but it works for me.

```
bool GraphicObject::IsMouseInside(int x, int y)
{
    if (Points.size() < 2)
    {
        return false;
    }

    int count = 0;
    float ti;
    float yint = y;
    float xint = 0;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < Points.size() - 1; i++)
    {
        auto p1 = Points[i + 1];
        auto p2 = Points[i];

        if (p1.x == x && p1.y == y)
        {
            return true;
        }

        ti = 0;

        if ((p2.y - p1.y) != 0)
        {
            ti = (yint - p1.y) / (p2.y - p1.y);
        }

        if (ti > 0 && ti < 1)
        {
            xint = p1.x + (p2.x - p1.x) * ti;

            // HACK: To point (line) are impossible to select.
            // Add an error margin.
            if (Points.size() == 2)
            {
                // TODO: Use euclidean distance for this. Is better?
                if ((xint + 8) > x || (xint - 8) > x)
                {
                    count++;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (xint > x)
                {
                    count++;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // last point with first.
    auto p1 = Points[Points.size() - 1];
    auto p2 = Points[0];

    ti = (yint - p1.y) / (p2.y - p1.y);

    if (ti > 0 && ti < 1)
    {
        xint = p1.x + (p2.x - p1.x) * ti;

        if (xint > x)
        {
            count++;
        }
    }

    return count % 2 != 0;
}
```